# Scichart's tick length having no effect

Tags: scichart

**sciChart3D WPF**.
I set up the `MajorTickLineStyle` and applied it to the X-axis. However, the tick mark on the X-axis shows an incorrect effect.

```xml
<Style x:Key="MajorTickLineStyle" TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="X2" Value="20"/>
</Style>

<s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>
    <s3D:NumericAxis3D TickTextBrush="Red"  x:Name="XAxis"
                       FontSize="20"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       TickLabelAlignment="ScreenAutoRotated"
                       MajorTickLineStyle="{StaticResource MajorTickLineStyle}" />
</s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>
```

sciChart tick length incorrect effect:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code and usage of the style is correct. It was a bug in SciChart SDK, which has already been fixed in v5.5.0.12243

Comment: It might be more helpful if you add a link to the version documentation you mentioned, to help the poster and future users with the same issue.